# Bash script to find a specific file in a directory and its subdirectories and execute 2 commands on that specific file

Tags: bash

Hello all I am really new in bash and need something really simple but can't figure. I need a bash script that I am calling in a pipeline to find a specific file "terragrunt.hcl". The bash should start looking from a directory (A) and its subdirectories (B, C, D, E, etc...) then execute 2 commands on each "terragrunt.hcl" file BUT have those 2 commands executed from inside the  directories where the file lives.

If I were to do it "by hand", it would look something like this:

```
cd A
(if terragrunt.hcl exist execute **command 1 && command 2** on terragrunt.hcl)
cd ../B
(if terragrunt.hcl exist execute **command 1 && command 2** on terragrunt.hcl)
cd ../C
(if terragrunt.hcl exist execute **command 1 && command 2** on terragrunt.hcl)
```

I did not really find anything really helpful so far. I found this online (https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/295965/how-to-use-find-exec-to-execute-command-in-directory-of-found-file-not-curre)  but it does not execute what I am fishing for.
Any help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If your platform's find supports it, try using `-exedir`

```
find . -name 'terragrunt.hcl' -execdir pwd \;
```

Replace `pwd` with your command that you want to run from that directory.

If you want to run multiple commands, you could do something like:

```
find . -name 'terragrunt.hcl' -execdir sh -c "command 1 && command 2" \;
```

Comment: When you find an answer useful, feel free to upvote it and accept it. This way the community can get it's feedback ;)